# Locating iframes in Python with Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I had to locate the iframe ,my html source code looks like

```
<iframe border="0" scrolling="yes" src="problem_list.do?sysparm_query=u_service_ticket_triage_group.name!%3Dxbt%20tech%20support%5Eu_program.name%3DTX_STAAR%5Eu_reject_ticket!%3Dtrue" name="TribName" width="100%" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100% !important; height: 800px !important;" frameborder="0" id="TribID"></iframe>
```

I tried using id and name to locate this iframe but i got error

> "no such element: Unable to locate element:"

Following are once that i tried

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_name("TribName")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("TribID")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Could you suggest on how I can select this iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided to switch to the desired frame you need to use *WebDriverWait* for the frame to be available and then switch using either of the methods :

- Through *Frame ID* :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
  # lines of code 
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"TribID")))
  ```
- Through *Frame Name* :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
  # lines of code         
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"TribName")))
  ```

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_id("TribID")))  ,Got error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: @Nav My solution doesn't includes `driver.find_element_by_id("TribID")` but **By.NAME,"TribName"**

Comment: Thanks ,but when i use sameway as u suggested I get error NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: @Nav That was my bad, added the relevant `import` and should work flawless. Let me know the status.

Comment: Posted a new question,Your help may do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe might be generate dynamically so you might need to explicitly wait for its appearance:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("TribID"))
```

In case of nested frames, e.g.

```
<iframe id="OuterFrame">
    <iframe id="TribID"></iframe>
</iframe>
```

you should switch sequentially to each frame starting from the high level ancestor:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("OuterFrame")
driver.switch_to.frame("TribID")
```